# What is best way to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 ?

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, dell, partitioning

I read many paper and I am just utterly confused . Some says don't use first option in Ubuntu install type (install Ubuntu alongside them) and you must use last option ( something else) .
Dell Inc says : If You want use something else . You must make partition with free space and use as Ex2 .
The other says : You must shrink volume windows drive and install Ubuntu use as Ex3.
What i must do finally ? If i make partition with my free space what is happen . what major problems have I encountered if i change my partition ( from windows to Linux )  ?
*_Thanks_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hard drive is divided into usable segments called partitions.  You can use your Ubuntu install disk (`gparted`) to check the available partitions and usage of your hard drive.  Normally having just one OS (operating system), you may have just one big partition in use.

You see a reference in your research to shrinking or making a new partition for a new OS installation.

Will `gparted` you can find the largest partition and shrink it.  Then you'll have unpartitioned space of which you can partition for Ubuntu.  Make it an ext4 partition.  You'll also need a swap partition.  I would recommend a swap partition at least the size, of the amount of ram you have in your computer.  In fact you'd best have a swap partition twice the size of your computer's ram.

So after shrinking your current partition and making space for your Ubuntu installation (at least 50 gigs) and your swap partition (at least 4 gigs). proceed with the install.

During the install, choose "Something else".  Then specify the new ext4 partition you created for your install.  It won't touch your other OS partitions.

When the install finishes you'll have a menu of either booting to Windows or Ubuntu with Ubuntu being the default.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the VirtualBox software or VMWare Desktop to create a virtual instance of Ubuntu.

You can install it directly from the downloaded ISO file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a flash drive. Boot Ubuntu from live cd in "try" mode, use gparted to partition flash drive (32gb recommend) install Ubuntu from live cd. Select install Ubuntu alongside windows, select (32gb flash) when prompted.